# JSON not displaying all values passed by string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, json

A div contains a table with 3 rows, a textarea and a button.
Using JSON the 3 rows display the correct info but the textarea is showing blank. I want it to display the previous record in the DB.

```
 function ChangeLoadingImage(CommentSuccessfullyUpdated) {
            if (CommentSuccessfullyUpdated != "FALSE") { 
                var x = jQuery.parseJSON(CommentSuccessfullyUpdated);

                $("#Item").text(x.Item);
                $("#Description").text(x.Description);
                $("#Price").text(x.Price);
                $("#ExistingComments").text(x.ExistingComments);
            }
            else if (CommentSuccessfullyUpdated == "False") {
                showLoadingImage.src = "../Images/X.png";
            }
        }


    <div id="dialog" title="Comments"  style="display:none;">
     <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
         <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Owed</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td id="Item"></td>
             <td id="Description"></td>
             <td id="Price"></td>
         </tr>
     </table> 


     <br />
           <textarea id="ExistingComments" type="text" runat="server" rows="7"
            maxlength="2000"> </textarea> 

            <input id="SubmitComment" type="button" value="Submit"
                onclick="SubmitButton()" />                          
    </div>
```

All the correct values are returning in the string. But instead of naming the td, iv named the textarea, but it isn't showing up. Any ideas as to why?

```
String result = "{" + string.Format("\"Item\": \"{0}\", \"Description\": \"{1}\", \"Price\": \"{2}\", \"ExistingComments\": \"{3}\"", Item, Description, Price, ExistingComments) + "}";

          return result;
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**EDIT:** 
I have also tried `alert(x.ExistingComments);` which does display the correct text.
Also tried `$("textarea#ExistingComments").text(x.ExistingComments);`which does nothing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('textarea').filter('[id*=ExistingComments]').val(x.ExistingComments);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Using JSON the 3 rows display the correct info but the textarea is
>   showing blank.

You can not call [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) on textarea rather you need [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

*Change*

```
 $("#ExistingComments").text(x.ExistingComments);
```

*To*

```
 $("#ExistingComments").val(x.ExistingComments);
```